# Gnome looks weird after logging in. When manager replaced works ok, until next re-login

Tags: gnome

I see garbage gnome screen every time I log in. Only menu works, but menus and icons look totally different. The rest of screen is some garbage, I don't even know how to explain it. I can open programs from "Applications" menu. Heh, there wasn't even "Applications" menu before.

I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, run `gnome-shell -r` (says it replaces manager) and then everything looks as it was, before system broke. I did nothing to it I swear :) But it happens every time I log out/log in.

Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Any ideas, what might be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have replaced the DM.
Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell` and pick gnome-shell as the DM

Comment: I think I need to change window manager, not DM. So far I did it stupid way : in startup applications entered gnome-shell -r. I've spend a good hour reading how to change default window manager, but huh couldn't find an answer.
I found by default my window manager is "metacity", when I do gnome-shell -r then i get "gnome" and then it's alright. But how to tell the system I want gnome to start in? 

And thank you for helping me!

Comment: the windows manager is part of the desktop. which DM are you using? If you don't want to use gnome-shell, then you need to switch desktop to match the DM that you are using

Comment: Yes but I have problems AFTER I login, not during login. DM is basicaly login screen, then Window Manager is what we see after logging in. 
* GNOME Shell is the graphical shell of the GNOME desktop environment.
* GDM (the GNOME Display Manager) is a display manager (a graphical login program) for the windowing systems X11 and Wayland.

So I need to switch window manager not DM. gnome-shell --help:
-r, --replace             Replace the running window manager

I want a permanent change. Don't know why it starts metacity after login.